# Program Analysis - Join over path vs Meet over path

Tags: analysis, static-analysis, symbolic-math, dynamic-analysis

MOP and JOP are commonly used concepts in program analysis. As far I know, MOP goes up the lattice and JOP goes down. However, I still need a solid definition + explanation (and applications) of both. Any answer would be appreciated.